# DragDrop between two FMX applications

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, firemonkey

Hi I need to drag an image from one application to another.  Both are Delphi FMX applications.  I was successful in doing it within one application but now need to transfer between two separate applications, ie no memory sharing.  I would be happy to save all info into a file and transfer the file name in the operation.  I do detect the dragover event in the receiving application but the data property is nil and I don't know how to populate it with a useful value.
I am using Windows 10, Delphi XE10.3
Any example, explanation will be helpful
Thank you

Comment: The proper way of doing this is OLE drag and drop. No intermediate file needed (or wanted).

Comment: That way you can even drag an image from a web browser or a Microsoft Office application to your app and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find an answer?

I am trying something similar.  Andreas is right about proper OLE, but it will be a lot of work to implement in FireMonkey.

The problem is that FireMonkey, on Windows, only interprets external drags of files (by their name and path) or unicode text.  It can accept other external drags, but extracts no information so it is useless.

Look in FMX.Platform.Win.
TWinFropTarget.GetDataObject() is the culprit.
PlatformWin.FDragAndDropActive is true for internal drags and false for external.
External drags of  CF_HDROP (filenames) and CF_UNICODETEXT (unicode text) only are interpreted.

To implement yourself steps would be

1. Roll your own IDropTarget.
2. Register it with Windows.  See TPlatformWin.CreateWindow(), call to RegisterDragDrop()
3. Create a mechanism for freeing it, which is all TWinWindowHandle.FWinDropTarget does, but FWinDropTarget is private.
4. Hook it up to the form or component that will receive the drop.
5. Enhance GetDataObject, or whatever replacement you have decided, to interpret the external drags that are of interest.  This requires more research.

Above generally covers the receiver.

The sender requires yet more research for how to initialise a Drag Drop of the content of interest in Windows.

Repeat for other platforms as required!

Drag and Drop component suite for VCL, https://torry.net/pages.php?id=233, probably has a lot of the code to do this, although I have not looked at it.

If anyone tries this, please update this thread.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30196398)

Comment: Sorry Jmb, but I beg to differ.  
The question is how to drag and drop an image between two Delphi FMX applications.  Andreas's answer is a concept only.  My answer is the steps to implement Andreas's concept in Delphi FMX, and therefore is an answer to the question.
If my post does not answer the question then Andreas's answer is simply wrong.  (But I think Andreas is right.)

Answer (score 0):

Andreas and my answers are about dragging the image itself.  In the question you suggest that sending the filename would be acceptable.  Following further research to solve my own issue I can give you the categoric answer for this solution, which avoids would be significantly less work.

Drag Drop, as you already know, involves a Source, a Target and Data.

Fire Monkey Drag Drop implementation for internal drags (i.e. within the application) uses its own data format, namely the Data record.  For internal drags only the Data.Source property is populated.

For external drags (i.e. between applications, whether FMX or not) OLE has to be used for the data.

All drags can be received by all open applications.  But unless OLE data has been set by the Source the Destination will be unable to interpret what the drag is or where it is from.  Your question states "I do detect the dragover event in the receiving application but the data property is nil".  You are experiencing the situation I am describing.

Delphi FMX will interpret and decode OLE data received for Files and Text content.  Files is a list of filenames with paths, not the files themselves.  Other OLE content is ignored, such as image.  See my previous answer for how to enhance FMX to interpret other OLE content.

Delphi FMX does not set OLE data.  Therefore to implement drag drop from a Fire Monkey application to another application, including another Fire Monkey application, it is necessary to write you own start drag code which populates OLE data.  In my previous answer this is written more briefly as "The sender requires yet more research for how to initialise a Drag Drop of the content of interest in Windows."

Such Drag Start code would be called from OnMouseDown event of the Source control.  For Windows I think

- create a COleDataSource
- set the data
- call its DoDragDrop method

I have not tried it because my application will not be a Source of inter-application drags.